# Word embedding as input or raw text?

Tags: neural-networks, text-mining, lstm, word2vec

I'm trying to implement a neural network for text recognition and I'm a little bit confused about text inputs.

The goal of the network is to classify a comment, toy example:

```
I like that -> GOOD
I don't like that -> BAD
```

For now I'm tokenizing my comments as:

```
[i, like, that]
[i, dont, like, that]
```

and my questions are:

- Should I input that list of words into the network? how?? one-hot encoding?
- I have read and tried Word2Vec but once I have my model should I translate the comment as a list of vectors? I mean:

In my Word2Vec model imagine that my '*i*' is *[0.23, 0.45, 0.1]*, '*like*' is *[0.67, 0.15, 0.98]* and '*that*' is *[0.43, 0.25, 0.72]*, My first input (*which were [i, like, that]*) should be now *[[0.23, 0.45, 0.1],[0.67, 0.15, 0.98],[0.43, 0.25, 0.72]]*?

In that case, I should be using Word2Vec to reduce dimensionality, right? so if with one-hot enconding I had a matrix of *WordNumber* * *WordNumber* now I should create vectors  *in order to have *WordNumber* * Vectorlength*, right?

Answer (score 1):

> Should I input that list of words into the network?

If you want to. It depends on what your goals are. If all you care about is maximizing performance on some hold-out set, then perhaps you should do an experiment to determine which method works best.

> how?? one-hot encoding?

Yes.

> I have read and tried Word2Vec but once I have my model should I translate the comment as a list of vectors?

Usually recurrent neural networks ([rnn](/questions/tagged/rnn), [lstm](/questions/tagged/lstm), [gru](/questions/tagged/gru)) are used in this scenario because they can naturally work with variable-length sequences.

Alternatively, you can just train the word embeddings simultaneously with the rest of the model. Pre-trained embeddings aren't strictly necessary, although if your training data is limited then maybe pre-trained embeddings could generalize better.

Answer (score 0):

I would use pretrained word embeddings with a neural network as Sycorax mentioned (recurrent or transformer) if you're looking for a good performance as state of the art models for sentiment analysis are nn-based nowadays.

You need to use the lookup index (word2idx) of the pretrained word embeddings to transform each word into an index then feed it into an embedding layer `nn.Embedding` in the case of pytorch for example. This layer would be initialized with the pretrained word vectors.

You can also have a look at using a pretrained language model like Bert for your use case which could help you overcome the small size of your dataset https://github.com/huggingface/pytorch-transformers